# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1 installation problems

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, svn, ios6

I'm finding it hard to hook up the new Facebook SDK properly. I followed [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) step-by-step guide and was very surprised by the fact that this version of the SDK requires an actual .pkg installation. Not only that, but the SDK needs to be referenced by the project (not copied into it). So what happens if someone checks out a working copy of the project and doesn't have the installation in the same exact relative path? Furthermore, I'm having difficulties configuring the SDK path so that it works even if the collaborators DO have the SDK installed in the same exact relative path (the SDK is not found and needs to be reattached for every commit).

This is a huge inconvenience and I was wondering if anyone ever tackled this problem successfully. I tried copying the resources into the project but no dice (doesn't build).

Thanks for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution: Add "~/Documents/FacebookSDK/ to the target's "Framework Search Paths" and also set "Always Search User Paths" to Yes.

Comment: What do you do with source control? how do you commit it there? does it commit it automatically if you don't have the full code?

Comment: Hi @Odelya since then we've started incorporating the actual files as well into the project to avoid problems with source control.

Comment: Thanks. where did you download the sources from? Also, which other dependencies did you have to add? since for instance I m missing FacebookSDKIntegrationTests/FBAppEventsIntegrationTests.m:17:9: 'OCMock/OCMock.h' file not found

Comment: Not using source files. We're using the compiled library and headers.

Comment: So how does it solve the source control problem? as the source control can't know about the dependencies etc

Comment: As it says that only the current user will be able to use the files. What do u mean by compiled library? where do you download it from?

Comment: This is the official Facebook SDK available at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37101/discussion-between-odelya-and-stavash)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it IS possible to hook up Facebook SDK 3.1.1 from sources.

Just get the sources from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk, then add "src/" folder to your project. And you'll have to delete "tests" and "Package" folders, they are not necessary.

Other steps (adding frameworks, linker flags) should be done according to guide. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try this and get back to you on the results.

Comment: Thanks, Nazar. It seems to be working. I find it disappointing that the new SDK code doesn't use ARC, but it's better than nothing...

Comment: Seems like this has raised some issues with my collaborators. Everyone is getting a "Can't run on current device" error.

Comment: strange, didn't face that issue. which version of iOS are you using?

Comment: iOS 6.0 on device and on Simulator

Comment: after updating to 3.1.1, faced this issue too. removing "info.plist" file from Framework/Resources folder fixes the problem

Comment: Don't have a "Resources" folder under the Framework folder. Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: did you try searching in facebook sdk folder? it is located somewhere and is the reason why you get "Can't run on current device" error.